# Let $a,b$ be integers, and let $m,n$ be positive integers. Show that if $a | (-b+2n)$ then $a \nmid (3b +7m)$ or $a \leq 6n+7m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem** Let $a,b$ be integers, and let $m,n$ be positive integers. Show that if
$a | (-b+2n)$ then $a  \nmid (3b +7m)$ or $a \leq 6n+7m$.

Thoughts:

By contradiction, if $a | (3b+7m)$ and $a>6n+7m$.

If $a>(6n+7m)$ then $a \nmid 6n+7m$ since $m,n$ are positive.

I'm not really sure how to proceed. Hints appreciated.

Example:

Suppose $a=b=1$, and $m=n=2$, then $1$ does divide $3b+7m=3(1)+7(2)=17$ but $a=1 < 6(2)+7(2)=26$, ok this works.

The role of $m$ seems a bit unclear to me. For instance I could try to find a multiple of $(2b+7m)$ added to some multiple of $(6n+7m)$ that is divisible by $a$,  that would somehow contradict that $a$ divides $(-b+2n)$, but not sure how.

Comment: try it with some numbers.

Comment: $a|(-b+2n)\Rightarrow a\not|(3b+7m)\lor a\le 6n+7m$ can be rewritten as $a|\lcm(-b+2n,3b+7m)\Rightarrow a\le 6n+7m$, and recall $a|c\Rightarrow a\le c$

Comment: Hint:  $\,a\,$ also divides every integral linear combination of those multiples. Choose one that eliminates $\,b\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically Equivalent to show the following: If $a|(-b +2n)$ and $a|(3b+7m)$, then $a \le (6n+7m)$.

So we show this next. To this end note the following: if $a|(-b+2n)$ then $a|3(-b+2n)=-3b+6n$. So $a$ divides both $-3b+6n$ and $3b+7m$, so $a$ divides the sum of these two integers which is $6n+7m$. But then if $a$ **divides** $6n+7m$ then $a$ must be **no larger than** $6n+7m$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$a|r$ and $a|s$ implies 
$a|(3r+s) \implies |a| \leq |(3r+s)|.$

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mike's answer...

Suppose by contradiction that $a|(-b+2n)$ and $a|(3b+7m)$ and $a > 6n+7m$. Then
$a|3(-b+2n)=-3b+6n$ and $a|(3b+7m)$ and so $a|(-3b+6n+3b+7m)=6n+7m$.

But then $a|6n+7m$ and $a>6n+7m$ where $6n+7m$ is positive. If $a\leq0$ this is impossible since $6n+7m$ is positive.

If $a>0$, then for any $b>c$ with $b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b,c > 0$ it is true that $b \nmid c$, therefore $a \nmid 6n+7m$, a contradiction, so the desired statement holds.